# Linqpad Identity impersonation - windows authentication

Tags: database-connection, linqpad

I have SQL server in one domain say PRDDomain (can connect only using windows auth)

I am working on second domain say STGDomain

now i want to run linq pad under prddomain\myuser , what should I do ? run as doesnt seem to work .

RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4\LINQPad.exe
1787: The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start LinqPad from the command Line with the following command:

```
runas /netonly /user:prddomain\myuser "C:\path\to\LinqPad.exe"
```

After you've issued the command you'll be asked for the correct user password. 
there might be problems, if there are no trust relationships between those 2 domains, but it's worth a try.

The `/netonly` parameter lets you run LinqPad(or any other executable) locally as yourself, in your case `STGDomain\username`, but remotly you are authenticated as `PRDDomain\username`.

Comment: "runas" works fine for my in SSMS and Sql Workbench, however I still get a connection error when trying to connect with LinqPad.

Comment: you could answer your own question with that specific error and point to this answer as a reference. I'm sure with a detailed description of the problem, that we can help you.